# Powering my projects and breadboard

Tags: power-supply, transformer, breadboard, wall-wart

I have a few differant AC to DC converters and wanted to know a good way to use them to power my breadboard and projects once they make it to strip/protoboard.

One adapter is used for laptops (Part No 608428-003). One is a 6V 500mA that will fit in a 2.1MM jack and another is a 12v 500mA that will fit into a 2.1MM jack. The final one is 6v at 2A and I can't figure out what jack I could use. (Model: DSA-0151A-06A)

So, I obviously can't hook them up straight to the breadboard or project board and get the magic 3.3v, 5v or any other value of volts I need. How would y'all suggest I lower the voltage and power my board?

Comment: buck regulators

Comment: If you can't figure out what jack to use, cut off the plug and solder on your own connector. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For low-current applications (less than 1A) you can use linear regulators to get the voltages you need. Just add one or more capacitors between + and - before and after them according to the datasheet of the regulator. The LM78XX/LM79XX line is the most popular for 5V and up, but there are others too. For 3V3 there are also many options, for instance the LM3940IT-3.3. Other voltages are equally easy to find, just search for "LDO" in a components distributor like DigiKey, Mouser, Farnell, etc. and filter for the current and voltage you need, and select the "through hole" mounting type since you're gonna use them in a breadboard.

Comment: I also do it this way.  There is even a 3.3V 78xx, though it is hard to get (Mouser has them, 78M33 IIRC).  The 78xx are not very efficient at >2V voltage difference, but they tend to be well-behaved. Also, at 1A you will need some cooling.

Comment: Just to clarify something. The 7805s are easy to use but there is a catch - you need at least 7V to get the 5V. This is the "dropout" voltage (2V).As fceconel points out, finding the right LDO - low dropout voltage - regulator can help significantly. Some have dropout voltages way lower than the 1V difference you have for 5V.

Comment: Would this work with my 12 volt wall-wart? http://www.taydaelectronics.com/lm7805-l7805-7805-voltage-regulator-ic-5v-1-5a.html

Comment: Also, how would I get the 6v wall-wort down to 5v if there is a 2v drop? Sorry if that's a dumb question :P

Comment: You either find a low dropout regulator, or use a bigger wall-wort. Keep in mind that the 78/79xx aren't meant for high current, they heat up real fast, I wouldn't run them at more than a few hundred mA without a heatsink. This is fine for a few breadboards or small projects, but probably not enough to run a dc motor for instance.

Comment: For higher power options there are also some ic based switching power supplies (see: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn150f.pdf), the one in the link provides 3 different voltages rated to a few amps each with only a handful of additional components. If you want something that you can "drop in" on your breadboard to avoid wiring up several regulators every time its something ot look at

Comment: @TheNickmaster21 as crasic mentioned, for 6V input you'll need another option instead, not the 78/79 lines, but they'd work OK with 12VDC.

Comment: Awesome; thanks. My final, and hopefully last question on this topic, is: Can I use ceramic caps in this circuit http://freedatasheets.com/blog/uploaded_images/7805datasheet-730100.gif

Comment: Not only you can, you should; if you can find ceramic with the capacitance+voltage you need, they are (in general) preferable over other types: more durable, non-polarized, etc. You go to aluminum/tantalum when the capacitance+voltage is so high that you can't find an equivalent ceramic or it is too expensive (which starts to be the case for more than a couple uF at 10s of V).

Comment: Hmm, okay. I found .33uF and .1uF ceramic caps for cheap :P

Comment: Also notice there are cheap ready-made regulators for what you want, like this http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10804 - but internally, they use the same LDO regulators you'd buy.

Comment: That's a 15 dollar component that I could make myself for less than 5...